# Change node size while running animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am making a fairly simple game for my own exploration in Swift.  So far I have the game running (no collisions) and all is well for the most part.  The game has objects spawn at the top of the screen and they increase in speed as you make it further through the game. The objective is to hop over as many objects as possible until you collide with one.  Pictured below is a screen shot of what I have so far.  The yellow glider at the bottom of the screen should jump over the object after a `touchesEnded` is detected.

I have made several images to make it appear as though my glider has jumped off the track to hop over the object.  I thought it would be fairly simple where I could run an animation after the player touches the screen because I made each individual frame (png) a different size (they are supposed to get bigger until it reaches max height of the jump and then back to smaller to land).  The issue I'm having is trying that when I call animate, it does not ever change the size of my images even though the have different pixel widths.  So my question is, how do I make it appear that my "glider" node is getting bigger as the animation runs and then back to smaller?  Can it be fixed in code? Do I need to store the images somewhere else (they are in a folder within my project called animation.atlas)?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This is a screen shot of the game, it is "birds eye view".]

Here is the code I'm using as of now just to animate (no resizing obviously because I can't figure it out). It runs through the array once, then again to go backwards as I made animations from beginning of jump to max height:

```
self.gliderSprite.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.animate(with: gliderTextureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: false),
                                            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1),
                                            SKAction.animate(with: gliderTextureArray.reversed(), timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: false)]))
```

Comment: scale, that is all

Comment: You should also run a group, not a sequence.

Comment: @ElTomato this is exactly what I needed. I used two groups instead of sequence (one for ascending, one for descending) and called run on those.  It works perfect now! thanks!

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have this problem fixed, but I added `categoryBitMask`, `collisionBitMask`, and `contactTestBitMask` to my "glider" for collisions now. Now my problem is that I can't turn off collisions while "jumping" over the pink balls.  Is there a way to do this so that collisions won't be detected during a jump animation? I tried quite a few things but none have worked.

Comment: Ask yourself why you added them in the first place..... then do the opposite

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm confused as to what you mean by that.. I figured that the proper way to do collision detection was to add physics bodies to my sprite nodes. Is this not the case?

Comment: you added bit masks to enable collision,  what would the opposite of that be

Comment: @Knight0fDragon to disable the bit masks, which I have tried doing in `touchesEnded` where I initiate my animations but didn't work. I set them to 0 and it didn't work (normally they are 1).

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, you want to make it appear as if your "ship" is jumping over the pink dots? This is extremely simple, just use `SKAction.scale`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if self.contains(location) {
            gliderSprite.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.scale(to: 1.3, duration: 0.7),
                                                SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5),
                                                SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.7)]))
        //The lower the duration, the quicker it will run.
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and functioning. I don't know how fast your game goes, so you will have to adjust the timings yourself.